# Apache mod_wsgi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'select'

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to set up an apache 2.4.57 server for a flask app (python ver 3.11.1) on windows 10. When I run httpd.exe and navigate to the relevant localhost page I get an internal server error. Checking the logs, I get the following stack trace:

```
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.747857 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047] mod_wsgi (pid=19784): Failed to exec Python script file 'path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file/FlaskApp.wsgi'.
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.748944 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047] mod_wsgi (pid=19784): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/git/Apache/FlaskApp.wsgi'.
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.749916 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/git/Apache/FlaskApp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from f import app as application\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\f\\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from f.main import app\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\f\\main.py", line 1, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from flask import Flask\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from . import json as json\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\json\\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from ..globals import current_app\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask\\globals.py", line 6, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug\\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     from .serving import run_simple as run_simple\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\werkzeug\\serving.py", line 19, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     import selectors\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]   File "path\to\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\selectors.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047]     import select\r
[Thu Oct 12 17:16:08.751860 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19784:tid 876] [client 127.0.0.1:53047] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'select'\r
```

This is incredibly strange, I think, as select is a standard library.

The flask app is a fairly simple hello world app (as I am attempting to set up a basic example):

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is then imported into an `__init__`.py file:

```
from f.main import app
```

My http.conf file points to the following FlaskApp.wsgi:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file/f")   
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file")   

from f import app as application
```

The httpd.conf file, I believe is configured correctly. The LoadFile, LoadModule and WSGIPythonHome are all copied from the output of `mod_wsgi-express module-config`. The httpd.conf file includes the following file, myapp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    servername flaskwill.com
    <Directory path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file/f>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / path/to/flask/and/wsgi/file/FlaskApp.wsgi   
</VirtualHost>
```

path/to/user looks something like C:/Users/John Smith/ as for whatever reason this was configured originally (not by me) to have a space in it. I believe this space is the reason I am not able to use mod_wsgi-express start-server (I get a syntax error in one of the files it creates that leads to a line with this path as part of it.) The fact it has found selectors.py indicates that this is unlikely to be the issue.

I have tried setting up a virtualenv instead of the basic venv, which did not change the output. The flask itself runs fine, and without the flask, the apache server runs fine. For instance, if I locate the application entirely within FlaskApp.wsgi, and do not call flask, I do not have any problems.

I really have no idea what else I can try. I have googled this problem extensively, and the only result that came close was "run pip install select" which won't work for obvious reasons.